# Fundamental theorem of calculus in high dimensions

Tags: calculus

we know the formula

$\int_a^b{d F(x) \over dx}dx=F(b)-F(a)$.

But how to generalize it to higher dimensions? Like

$\int_{(a,b)}^{(c,d)}DF(x,y)dxdy=?$ or $F(x,y)-F(p,q)=?$

I began to think of such questions because i wanted to prove  the following formula

$\sup {|u(x)-u(y)| \over |x-y|^{1-{n \over p}}} \le||Du||_{L^p}$

I surfed the internet and found the co-area formula may be helpful. But I didn't know how to use it.

Comment: Stokes theorem. But be prepared for some baggage.